# How to display array of json data properly in html?

Tags: php, arrays, json

My Ajax

```
$("form").on("submit", function () {
    var data = {
        "action": "test"
    };

    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "ajax2.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {

            $("#main_content").slideUp("normal",function(){

            $(".the-return").html("<br />JSON: " + data);
//how to alter this part to display data for each record in one div?

            });
        }
    });
    return false;

});
```

My query

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE subid IN (:key2) AND Poscode=:postcode2");
    $statement->execute(array(':key2' => $key2,':postcode2'=>$postcode));
 // $row = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $json = array();
 while( $row = $statement->fetch()) {
     array_push($json, array($row['Name'], $row['PostUUID']));
 }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($json);
```

The result displayed currently in this form:

```
JSON: jack,55421894ab602,test,55439324cc43d
```

But I want to display like:

```
 Name:jack,
 Id:55421894ab602
.....and some other info-

 Name:test
 Id:55439324cc43d
.....and some other info-
```

This part:

```
$(".the-return").html("<br />JSON: " + data);
```

I tried: `data[0];`
But when I do this, only the first record displayed obviously.

What I'm trying is :

`data[0]` itself is an array. How to display that array together with other records fetched in nice html?

edited: WIth these edited code, i can only retrieve the last result, it's not looping through the array.

ajax
    success: function (data) {

```
            $("#main_content").slideUp("normal",function(){

            //$(".the-return").html("<br />JSON: " + j_data);
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $(".the-return").html("<div>Name:" + data[i].name + "<br/>Id:" + data[i].id);
        }
            console.log(data); // this shows nothing in console,I wonder why?
            //alert(j_data);
            });
        }
```

php

```
$json = array();
 while( $row = $statement->fetch()) {
     //array_push($json, array($row['Name'], $row['PostUUID']));
     array_push($json, array("name" => $row['Name'], "id" => $row['PostUUID']));
 }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Assign them in an variable like $variable = json_decode($json). $variable will be array type and then you can use it easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to get the names of the fields in your template, you need store them in your array:

```
array_push($json, array("name" => $row['Name'], "id" => $row['PostUUID']));
```

Result after json_encode -> {"name":"TheName","id":"TheID"}

Next, in your js code, if the json that it receives is valid, you can do a loop:

```
success: function (data) {
    $("#main_content").slideUp("normal",function(){
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $(".the-return").html("<div>Name:" + data[i].name + "<br/>Id:" + data[i].id);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you can add style or class to the div.

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks but the result in html says like this:JSON: [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: Are you doing the loop? If you try to print it directly, the result is that, a json object. You have to access to the values.

Comment: I just copy pasted your codes for array push and javascript??

Comment: I got something now.. i simpley copy pasted your code and i can get result by name specified in array like name, id..but only one result..it's not looping though

Comment: [Object, Object]
[Object, Object]

Comment: that looping supposed to have two records but it's only showing one..that's my problem...apart from that i can access the data by name as you specified

Comment: I just try with this example: [{"name":"TheName","id":"TheID"},{"name":"TheName2","id":"TheID2"}] and works fine (on my javascript console) I think is another problem. Can you update your question with the new problem? (and upvote my answer, if you likes, thanks :))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77113/discussion-between-pabgaran-and-sherly).